# Trying to make layered navigation accordion style (with divs)

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

Trying to make this work but seems not having any effect... What am I doing wrong?

With help from @Shyam I got the following working solution:

```
<div id="narrow-by-list">
    <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
    <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <div class="widget <?php echo strtolower($this->__($_filter->getName())) ?>">
            <div class="block-title">
                <h3 class="section-title heading">
                <?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content block-content"><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#narrow-by-list .widget-content").hide();
        jQuery("#narrow-by-list a").click(function(){
            jQuery("#narrow-by-list .widget-content:visible").slideUp("fast");
            jQuery(this).next(".widget-content").slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery code, you're using child selector ( > ) which only selects immediate children.

And in your HTML, .widget-content div is not immediate child of parent #narrow-by-list div.

Please try below jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#narrow-by-list .widget-content").hide();
    jQuery("#narrow-by-list .blocktitle").click(function(){
        jQuery("#narrow-by-list .widget-content:visible").slideUp("fast");
        jQuery(this).next(".widget-content").slideToggle("fast");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope it will help..

Comment: Edited post with your solution, added some more to it to make it work completely.

Comment: do you also know how to make it close again when you click on the same div? Now you have to click on a different blocktitle to make the other one close; but can the script also be changed so you're able to close the one thats open?